# Qt moving an Object in a specific Region

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I'm new to Qt programming. So far I made a `QGraphicsScene` draw some rectangles (looks like a Chess Board) and then added an own `QGraphicsItem` to the scene. For this item I set the `ItemIsMovable` flag. Now I can move it but I would like to restrict the movement to the area where the Chess Board is.

Would I have to unset the flag and realize the movement manually or is there like an option or flag where I can specify the area it can be moved in ?

```
renderableObject::renderableObject(QObject */*parent*/)
{
    pressed = false;
    setFlag(ItemIsMovable);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reimplement the `QGraphicsItem`'s `itemChange()` if you want to restrict movable area. Repositioning the item will cause `itemChange` to get called. You should note that `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag is needed to capture the change in position of `QGraphicsItem`.

```
class MyItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    MyItem(const QRectF & rect, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0);
protected:
    virtual QVariant    itemChange ( GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value );
};


MyItem::MyItem(const QRectF & rect, QGraphicsItem * parent )
    :QGraphicsRectItem(rect,parent)
{
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
}

QVariant MyItem::itemChange ( GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value )
{
    if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene()) {
        // value is the new position.
        QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
        QRectF rect = scene()->sceneRect();
        if (!rect.contains(newPos)) {
            // Keep the item inside the scene rect.
            newPos.setX(qMin(rect.right(), qMax(newPos.x(), rect.left())));
            newPos.setY(qMin(rect.bottom(), qMax(newPos.y(), rect.top())));
            return newPos;
        }
    }
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

This will keep item moving limited to scene rect. You can define any arbitrary rect if you like.